# multi line textbox overflows window instead of displaying scrollbar

Tags: wpf, textbox, scrollbar, .net-4.5

In the following XAML, I have a multiline textbox. When empty, it displays one row, and as you type if expands. That part goes well, it expands row after row as I type in and does not overflow horizontally. However, comes a moment when my groupBox hits the bottom of the window, pushed by the textbox's size, and goes out of sight. What to do for a scrollbar to appear when the border of the window is met ? The textbox in question is declared close to the bottom of this piece of code.

```
<GroupBox Header="News Item Selected" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <DockPanel>
                    <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Name="SlaveViewGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="Index:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                        <Label Content="Title:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
                        <Label Content="Image:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
                        <Label Content="Label:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
                        <Label Content="Url:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
                        <Label Content="Text 01:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" />
                        <Label Content="Text 02:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6" />
                        <Label Content="Text 03:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" />
                        <Label Content="Summary Text:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="8" />

                        <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="txtSelectedViewIndex" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Index}"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewTitle" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <Image Name="imgSelectedViewImage" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewLabel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Text="{Binding Label}"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewUrl" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Text="{Binding Url}"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewText01" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" Text="{Binding Text01}"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewText02" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="6" Text="{Binding Text02}"/>
                        <TextBox Name="txtSelectedViewText03" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Text="{Binding Text03}"/>
                        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
         AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtSelectedViewSummaryText" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="8" Text="{Binding SummaryText}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DockPanel>
            </GroupBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you set the height of row 8 of the Grid to Auto. Auto does not limit the height, that in turn means the TextBox does not get any limits and expands as needed and see no need to show the scrollbar. Just set a height and you are done.

Comment: Yes, that would be an idea, but what I'm after is a little different

Comment: Could you please go a bit more in detail how you want the scrolbar to appear. Next to the TextBox, the GroupBox, ...